# How to get Selenium to cycle through a hierarchy dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have this link that I have to scrape parts from: https://partsurfer.hp.com.
To get to each part I first need to cycle through a series of clicks to make the elements visible. An example is the image below:[image]

My code, however gets stuck after going through one cycle. I cannot seem to get it to go through several times. Please take a look at my code. I would appreciate any ideas to assist me write the loop properly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from time import sleep

options1 = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options1.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="~~chromedriver.exe", options=options1)

url = 'https://partsurfer.hp.com'
driver.get(url)
sleep(5)

# deal with popup
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']").click()

# select country and reload the page
dropdowns = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_ddlCountry'))
dropdowns.select_by_value('ZA')
driver.refresh()
sleep(5)

# click hierarchy and cycle through the list to the parts 
hierarchy_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_aHierarchy']/span[@class='ie_bg']/span").click()
sleep(5)
category_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@width='650']/tbody/tr/td/a")
for a in category_list:
    breadcrumb1 = a.text
    print(breadcrumb1)
    a.click()
    sleep(2)
    series_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_HierarchyTreen1Nodes']/table/tbody/tr//a")
    for b in series_list:
        breadcrumb2 = b.text
        print(breadcrumb2)
        b.click()
        sleep(2)
        series_2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_HierarchyTreen2Nodes']/table/tbody/tr//a")
        for c in series_2:
            breadcrumb3 = c.text
            print(breadcrumb3)
            c.click()
            sleep(2)
            series_3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_HierarchyTreen3Nodes']/table/tbody/tr//a")
            for d in series_3:
                breadcrumb4 = d.text
                print(breadcrumb4)
                d.click()
                sleep(2)
                series_4 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_HierarchyTreen4Nodes']/table/tbody/tr//a")
                for e in series_4:
                    breadcrumb5 = e.text
                    print(breadcrumb5)
                    e.click()
                    sleep(2)
                    models = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='table_sortable']/tbody//a")
                    for model in models:
                        model_num  = model.text
                        print(model_num)
                        model.click()
                        sleep(5)
                        # model number = //span[@id='ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_lblProductNumber']
                        table_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_dvProdinfo']/table/tbody/tr")
                        for row in table_rows:
                            print(row.text)
```

My code isn't complete, so would love to get any inputs to improve its efficiency.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, if you need a debuger pls go to Debugoverflow

Comment: Use indexing to get the next element so get the total elements and then loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
driver.get('https://partsurfer.hp.com')

# deal with popup
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()

# select country and reload the page
dropdowns = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_ddlCountry'))
dropdowns.select_by_value('ZA')


# click hierarchy and cycle through the list to the parts
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@id='ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_aHierarchy']/span[@class='ie_bg']/span"))).click()


category_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@width='650']/tbody/tr/td/a")
for i in range(1,len(category_list)):
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//table[@width='650']/tbody/tr/td/a)["+str(i)+"]"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_HierarchyTreet0"))).click()
```

Here's a small demo to go through the top level. You want to use the Top Hierarchy to reset yourself.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: was wondering why would you have to `driver.refresh()`?

Comment: oh forgot to remove it

Comment: @undetected Selenium `driver.refresh()` is necessary because the page needs to reload when you change the location. It does not do that automatically